# Day CQ Mail Service Configuration not working

Tags: osgi, aem

We are using Day CQ Mail Service Configuration to send mails. I have referenced the configuration using the following code in my service impl.

```
@Reference
private MessageGatewayService messageGatewayService;

@Reference
private MessageGateway<HtmlEmail> messageGateway;
```

We are supplying the configuration values through the config nodes.After the code build , we are able to see the SMTP server values in the Day CQ Mail Service Felix configuration. The issue is that when I am submitting the form to send a mail , it throws a **MailingException logging "Invalid Mail Service Configuration"**. Even though the configuration values are all proper , it still throws the same exception.

To resolve this issue , we went to the corresponding bundle "**Day Communique 5 Mailercom.day.cq.cq-mailer**" and restarted the bundle. Then the configuration started working and we were able to send emails.

Why do I have to explicitly go and restart the CQ OOTB Bundle to make the configuration work ?

Answer (score 3):

Did you have changed the configuration setting in Config manager, 
    http://localhost:4502/system/console/configMgr
Search and Select DAY CQ Mailer service and add the following configuration:

```
SMTP server host:smtp.gmail.com
SMTP server port:465
SMTP user:username@gmail.com
SMTP password:gmail_password
“From” address:userName@gmail.com
SMTP use SSL:true
```

Click 'save'. The Mail configuration will be saved on your felix console.

Also, turn on the 'Allow less secure apps' in your mail setting.

Hope this will help.